# Specifying which parameter to pass

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, default-parameters

Consider that I have a method like below, in C#.

```
void DoSomething(bool arg1 = false, bool notify = false)
{ /* DO SOMETHING */ }
```

I can specify which parameter I pass to method like this:

```
DoSomething(notify: true);
```

instead of

```
DoSomething(false, true);
```

Is it possible in Javascript?

Comment: It seems that you've confused Javascript with Java.

Comment: No, it's not. Call-time named arguments is not supported by Javascript.

Comment: There is only one type of variable in JavaScript and i.e `var`

Comment: @varit05 "Types" of variables are things like `boolean`, `Number`, `String` etc. The `var` keyword does something different, and there *are* more of those in ES6 like `const` and `let`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, but you can workaround it by passing objects and adding some custom code

```
/**
 * This is how to document the shape of the parameter object
 * @param {boolean} [args.arg1 = false] Blah blah blah
 * @param {boolean} [args.notify = false] Blah blah blah
 */
function doSomething(args)  {
   var defaults = {
      arg1: false,
      notify: false
   };
   args = Object.assign(defaults, args);
   console.log(args)
}

doSomething({notify: true}); // {arg1: false, notify: true}
```

And you could generalize this

```
createFuncWithDefaultArgs(defaultArgs, func) {
    return function(obj) {
        func.apply(this, Object.assign(obj, defaultArgs);
    }
}

var doSomething = createFuncWithDefaultArgs(
    {arg1: false, notify: false}, 
    function (args) {
         // args has been defaulted already

    }
);
```

Note that `Object.assign` is not supported in IE, [you may need a polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill)

Comment: Never knew about the `Object.assign` method! It seems like something that popped up in numerous frameworks, usually as "mixin". That's handy.

Answer (score 2):

The common convention for ES2015 is to pass [an object as a single argument](http://www.2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html#simulating-named-parameters-in-javascript), assign default values for it's properties and than use destructuring inside the function:

```
const DoSomething = ({ arg1 = false, notify = false } = {}) => {
  /* DO SOMETHING */
};

DoSomething({ notify: true }); // In the function: arg1=false, notify= true
```

You can call this function without any arguments at all, i.e. `DoSomething()`, but this requires default value for the object (`= {}` at the end of the arguments list).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve something similar by passing an object:

```js
function DoSomething(param) {
  var arg1 = param.arg1 !== undefined ? param.arg1 : false,
      notify = param.notify !== undefined ? param.notify : false;

  console.log('arg1 = ' + arg1 + ', notify = ' + notify);
}

DoSomething({ notify: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass object as argument:

```
function DoSomething(obj){

 if (obj.hasOwnProperty('arg1')){

  //arg1 isset
 }

 if (obj.hasOwnProperty('notify')){

  //notify isset
 }

}
```

usage:

```
DoSomething({
 notify:false
});
```

Comment: What if the user passes `{arg1: window.__dont_exist}`? A better test is `obj.hasOwnProperty('arg1')` or `'arg1' in obj`

Comment: Thanks @JuanMendes